# Flask URL Redirects Where Parameter is Part of URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, flask

I would like to redirect to the URL which has a namespace containing the ID. The route for the view looks like:

```
@app.route('/gosign/<string:object_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gosign(object_id):
```

I have tried the below which gives werkzeug.routing.BuildError:

```
return redirect(url_for("gosign/", object_id=object_id))
```

I have also tried the below which gives the same error:

```
return redirect(url_for("gosign/" + object_id))
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url_for` requires the name of the function, not the route path. So all you need to do is remove the trailing `/`.

```
return redirect(url_for("gosign", object_id=object_id))
```